# Cannot connect to router while being connected to provider

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, openwrt

I have TP-Link + Luci + OpenWrt router. I live in a dormitory where some external system is used to control user's connections.
The main problem is that after I plug a twisted pair to my router I cannot access its interface through 192.168.1.1 via wifi. And as soon as I unplug it - it is possible.
Also, I can try to access it only using wifi, because there is just one socket for a twisted pair.
Question: how can I configure my router in order to reach it with the plugged twisted pair?

Comment: This sounds like an IP conflict... Have you tried changing the IP Address of your router? Otherwise more information is needed, IP addresses, subnets. gateways, physical connections, settings, DHCP, etc... It is impossible to troubleshoot this with the given information.

Comment: @acejavelin Thank you for your reply! I have changed it to another and still doesn't work. My router's information: IP - 192.168.1.10, 255.255.255.0 and other fields are empty. My wifi laptop adapter's, information: Connection-specific DNS Suffix - kou.pks.muni.cz, Link-local IPv6 Address - fe80::9c27:bdf1:51bd:a115%10, IPv4 Address - 147.251.210.142, Subnet Mask - 255.255.255.0, Default Gateway - 147.251.210.1

Comment: A network connection drawing would be helpful. It's unclear from your messages which devices are attached to which networks. In particular, your last comment indicated that your laptop is connected to a 147.251.210.0/24 network and not the 192.168.1.0/24 network so you are trying to access a router which you are not actually connected to...